# Set Parent to Instantiated Objects in Unity

Tags: unity, gameobject

i am having problem in attaching parent to the instantiated objects. I have attached the code below. please tell me where i am doing wrong. Thank you.

```
public GameObject brick;
public Transform BrickHolder;
//public GameObject Bricks;

void Start(){
    for (float y = 2.16f; y < 4.88f; y += 0.34f){
        for (float x = -2.125f; x <= 2.125f; x += 0.85f){

            GameObject Bricks = Instantiate(brick, new Vector3(x, y, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;

            if (Bricks != null) {
                Debug.Log("Hello");
                Bricks.transform.SetParent(BrickHolder);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe BrickHolder is null. Where do you istantiate it? test if it is null.

Comment: i created an object and attached it to brickholder. its isn't showing any null now but parent isn't getting assigned.

Answer (score 1):

I have personally never used `SetParent()`. I have always used the `parent` property, like so:

```
Bricks.transform.parent = BrickHolder;
```

This should be pretty much equivalent though, so I don't expect that is the issue *(confirmed in comments already)*. The difference is that `SetParent()` allows you to update the child transform in relation to the parent, or not (with the second boolean parameter: `worldPositionStays`).

Update:
If `BrickHolder` is `null`, Unity will happily accept it without error, since it's valid to unparent a child object. Make sure that `BrickHolder` has been assigned.

Update2:
If `Bricks` is also `null`, that would suggest that `brick` is not valid (probably also `null`). You will need to make sure both `brick` and `Brickholder` have been assigned to your component in the inspector or through another script.

The only other suggestion I can offer is that sometimes you need to reset your component (the one in your question) in the inspector or remove and reattach. Sometimes Unity doesn't update the serialized values if it thinks they haven't changed, so may be referencing invalid objects.

Comment: I've just tried both but still couldn't resolve the issue :(

Comment: Sorry, just noticed that you have BrickHolder defined as a Transform in the code of your question which means the first part of my answer is incorrect. I should ask, is BrickHolder null? You didn't indicate if Unity is producing any errors, so it's difficult to guess what the problem may be.

Comment: [DEL] Sorry, late comment.

Comment: Its ok. Yes, BrickHolder is Null and also Bricks is showing Null While Debugging. I'm attaching the image. http://i.imgur.com/pBNczVs.png
Unity is showing no errors.

Comment: @penta_d I've updated my answer. If none of those suggestions work, then I'm at a loss.

Comment: no matter what i do  
`GameObject Bricks = Instantiate(brick, new Vector3(x, y, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;` nothing is getting stored in bricks it is always null and hence it is never entering the next if condition  `if (Bricks != null) {
                Debug.Log("Hello");
                Bricks.transform.SetParent(BrickHolder);
            } `

Comment: @FuzzyLogic m able to assign instantiated object to Bricks now but unable to attach BrickHolder as its parent.

 `public GameObject instantBrick;
 public Transform BrickHolder;
 //public GameObject Bricks;

 void Start(){
  for (float y = 2.16f; y < 4.88f; y += 0.34f){
   for (float x = -2.125f; x <= 2.125f; x += 0.85f){

    GameObject Bricks = GameObject.Instantiate(instantBrick, new Vector3(x, y, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
    Bricks.transform.SetParent(BrickHolder);

 
   }
  }
 }`

Comment: @FuzzyLogic thanks for your help. Following Line Solved my problem :) `Bricks.transform.parent = GameObject.Find ("BrickHolder").transform;`

Answer (score 1):

No need to add an assignment or setter call to establish the parent relationship. Simply, specify the fourth, `parent` argument for `Instantiate`, which, if supplied, needs to be a `Transform`. See it in the [Unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html).

Comment: this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could replicate the issue your having is by the "BrickHolder" variable being unassigned. I would make sure that it is assigned in the inspector.

Comment: just tried... no luck..